# Doxygen documentation after members - malfunction cause formatting as code fragment?

Tags: doxygen

I'm running doxygen 1.8.3.1 under SLED 10.4 (linux), and am trying to document a C header file which contains structs similar to the following:

```
/** Test struct definition */
typedef struct
{
    int member_1;  /**< Single-line detailed description */
    int member_2;  /**< Multi-line detailed description.  Blah
                        blah blah */
} TEST_S;
```

Doxyfile is the default as generated by `doxygen -g`, with the only change being that I have edited the INPUT tag to point to my source.

Doxygen generates simple memdoc paragraphs from the single-line descriptions as expected, however, the multi-line descriptions are somehow being handled such the first line gets formatted as a code fragment.  I have no idea why.  The actual HTML that is generated is as follows:

```
<pre class="fragment">  Multi-line detailed description.  Blah
</pre><p> blah blah </p>
```

Why isn't Doxygen generating just a simple paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be bug in Doxygen's support for Markdown in the 1.8.3.1 release (I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with Doxygen 1.8.2). If you disable markdown support in the configuration file:

```
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = NO
```

The page is rendered correctly.

Alternatively if you switch your comment to a leading doxygen comment:

```
/** Multi-line detailed description.  Blah
    blah blah */
int member_2;
```

Or move the comment to the following line:

```
int member_2;
/**< Multi-line detailed description.  Blah
     blah blah */
```

it should be rendered correctly.

This issue has been reported to the Doxygen development group (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=699437).

Comment: The mentioned issue has been fixed in doxygen 1.8.4 and the output in the current version 1.8.15 is still OK.