# Doxygen @snippet html style spill over to next markup tag

Tags: html, css, alias, doxygen

So I have this custom command in doxygen:

```
ALIASES = " \
codeexamples{3}= \
@htmlonly[block] \
<div class=\"snippettab\"> \
  <button class=\"snippettablinks\" onclick=\"openExTab(event,'langcs_\1_code_snippet')\">C#</button> \
  <button class=\"snippettablinks\" onclick=\"openExTab(event,'langvb_\1_code_snippet')\">VB</button> \
</div> \
@endhtmlonly \
<div id=\"langcs_\1_code_snippet\" class=\"snippetcontent\"> \snippet \2 \1_code_snippet^^ </div> \
<div id=\"langvb_\1_code_snippet\" class=\"snippetcontent\"> \snippet \3 \1_code_snippet^^ </div> \
"
```

And here is an example on how I use it:

```
/*!@brief brief description.
 * 
 *        Detailed description
 *        
 *@note   A note
 *
 *        \codeexamples{Initialize,Test.cs,Test.vb}
 *        
 *@sa OnInitialized\n Reset()\n TStorage
 */
```

The `codeexamples{}` command works fine but the next command `@sa` is not parsed but printed as it is with the class: `class='fragment'`, same class as the example code.

```
<div id="langvb_Initialize_code_snippet" class="snippetcontent" style="display: block;">
  <div class="fragment">...</div>
  <!-- fragment -->
</div>
<pre class="fragment">   @sa OnInitialized\n Reset()\n TStorage</pre>
```

As you can see the `@sa` is not parsed. It's like it never saw the `@endhtmlonly` but doxygen doesn't complain or warn for anything and there are no errors in the web browser when displaying it.

I have alos tried other commands than `@sa` but whatever command I put there, it's not parsed by doxygen and displayed as text.

Is it a bug in doxygen or have I overlooked something?

**EDIT**
It seems like this is a bug. doxygen puts a `<pre class="fragment">` after the inserted code:

[Doxygen documentation after members - malfunction cause formatting as code fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326563/doxygen-documentation-after-members-malfunction-cause-formatting-as-code-fragm)

The solution to end the block and start a new one solves it:

```
/*!@brief brief description.
 * 
 *        Detailed description
 *        
 *@note   A note
 *
 *        \codeexamples{Initialize,Test.cs,Test.vb}
 */        
 //!@sa OnInitialized\n Reset()\n TStorage
```

Comment: ALIAS -> ALIASES. Doxygen version 1.8.14 (from an earlier question) What is the contents of Test.cs and Test.vb? As what is Test.vb parsed.

Comment: Do you have any other configuration option set? Why do you use so much space before the detailed description and the `\codeexamples`? Maybe set `MARKDOWN_SUPPORT=NO` or decrease the amount of space before the mentioned entities. Please construct a complete example and show an image where the problem occurs.

Comment: ALIAS is a typo here, In my Doxygen file it says ALIASES. MARKDOWN_SUPPORT = Yes and Its only 1 empty line between each command. Here the text is just one liners to show the concept. In the real documentation it's of course a lot more descriptive text on all segments. I will try to narrow down the example to a minimum and update.

Comment: It appears to be a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326563/doxygen-documentation-after-members-malfunction-cause-formatting-as-code-fragm

Comment: The problem mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326563/doxygen-documentation-after-members-malfunction-cause-formatting-as-code-fragm has already been fixed in version 1.8.4 and in the current version (and also in 1.8.14) still works.

Comment: I still don't see the problem you have. Please post the wrong and correct image. The only problem I see is the indentation problem before detailed description and the `\codeexamples`, but the output here looks correct to me (8 spaces > 4 spaces => code fragment due to markdown syntax).